# Morris chart centered label showing vertically invrted in safari browser

Tags: javascript, charts, dashboard, morris.js, donut-chart

I am using morris donut chart. It works fine in firefox and chrome. But look bellow I dont know what happened to it in safari browser. I have used simpple donut chart script no more options
let me know if you want source  code as it is working fine in other browser I think there is no need of source code

[image]

```
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'morris-donut-chart_application',
    colors: colorArray1,
    data: <?php echo json_encode($new1); ?>,
    formatter: function(x, data){
        if(data.empty==true){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return x;
        }
    }
```

colorArray1 and $new1 are array and please note that code is working correctly in firefox and chrome
I think this is something with extra js or css

Comment: Nevertheless, show us the code.

Comment: Thanks for @Eucar Comment The chart script is working properly..

Comment: But just labels are not showing properly in safari browser only